# Can't access /data/data/etc from native code?

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, sharedpreferences

It seems I can't access any file in /data/data/com.my.app/ from my program in native code. The Java installer can write in that folder but fopen from native code always returns NULL. My C program (in the form of a shared library .so) is loaded in an external app, a GUI, developed by someone else. Is that the reason? My native code, when loaded in a GUI, can only access the GUI reserved dir? (/data/data/com.the.gui etc)

If that's the reason how can I make my Java and native code communicate?
I don't think using /sdcard is a good solution.
Perhaps using SharedPreferences and JNI in native code? How to read a string from SharedPreferences using JNI?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Um, do you have two separate apps here? What is the relationshp between `com.my.app` and `com.the.gui`? Which of those did you write?

Comment: I wrote com.my.app which include some Java code and my native program in C. com.the.gui is any GUI written by someone else.

Comment: "com.the.gui is any GUI written by someone else" -- then I fail to see how your native code would be loaded in somebody else's app. ("My native code, when loaded in a GUI, can only access the GUI reserved dir? (/data/data/com.the.gui etc)"). Your JNI-linked native code should have read/write access to your app's [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html). It may not be that path, though. Pass a known-valid file path (e.g., created based on `getFilesDir()`) to the native code via JNI.

Comment: My C program can access any file in /sdcard but can't in /data/data/com.my.app. I got /data/data/com.my.app using getFilesDir().getPath() in Java. How to use it with JNI? (and read SharedPreferences too). Can you point me to some doc that explains it? Thanks.

Comment: "My C program" -- hopefully, you mean "my C library, compiled using the NDK and linked to my Android app via JNI". If your native code is a standalone program, I am uncertain as to what that has access to; this approach is not commonly used with Android. "How to use it with JNI?" -- um, pass the Java `String` as a parameter to your JNI-defined function, which then is a `jstring` in Java code.

Comment: It's a standalone program. I need a way for the Java part, which is executed only once after the APK installation, to write a string in a file and the native program to read that string each time is loaded in a GUI.

Comment: Just to be clear, there's no difference in access between native and Java-language code. The restriction is imposed by the operating system based on the user ID of the process. Any file operation you can do from Java can be done from native, and vice-versa. Check your filenames and look at the error code in `errno` if something is failing that you think should be succeeding.

Comment: @Andrew did you find any way to write and read data with JNI on data folder?